# Linked list in C, names overwrite

Tags: c, linked-list

Help me, I am just a newbie.

I am currently studying and practicing linked list in C. I want to arrange the names of the instruments according to their sizes.

Problem is, every time I create a new instrument, the names of the previous instruments are overwritten by my newly created instrument but the sizes are not overwritten.

Why and What's happening there?

for example, the first instrument is "FLUTE" and size is 1, it will display those info. But when the 2nd loop comes and I input the second instrument ex., name is "TRUMPET" and size is 3, "FLUTE" gone..! It will display

name: TRUMPET, size: 1 //but the size is still there.

name: TRUMPET, size: 3

```
//here's my main
int main(void)
{
    int add = 1;
    int size;
    char name[30];
    instrument *start = NULL;
    instrument *x = NULL;
    instrument *y = NULL;
    instrument *next = NULL;

    while(add != 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the instrument: ");
        scanf(" %29s", name);

        printf("Size: ");
        scanf(" %d", &size);

        next = pos(name, size);

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = next;
        }

        if(x != NULL)
        {
            x->next = next;
        }

        x = next;
        //for now, I'll just display the instruments instead of sorting them.
        displayInstruments(start);

        printf("\nDo you want to add more?: ");
        scanf(" %d", &add);
    }

    freeInstruments(start);

    return 0;
}

//this is my instrument creator function
instrument* pos(char *name, int size)
{
    instrument *i = malloc(sizeof(instrument));
    i->name = name;
    i->size = size;
    i->next = NULL;

    return i;
}

//and other codes below here that don't matter for now. . . . . . . .
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: call `pos(strdup(name),size)` this will make a copy of the name

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it. So I need to copy the name first since they are all pointing at the same address. Tnx. But  about the space that the function "strdup()" created, where will it go?  stack or on the heap?

Comment: heap - and u have to free it (there are no free lunches in C land)

Comment: tnx pm100......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single buffer to store the `name` of each instrument. By default, `int`s will be copied so that you are correctly storing the size of each instrument. With strings, however, you store a pointer which holds the memory location of string. All of your `instrument->name` pointers are pointing to the same memory location, so they will all display the most recently added instrument name.

To fix this, change `i->name = name` to `i->name = strdup(name)`, which will duplicate the string and create it's own personal copy.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it. So I need to copy the name first since they are all pointing at the same address. Tnx. But  about the space that the function "strdup()" created, where will it go?  stack or on the heap?

Comment: It will be allocated on the heap.

Comment: tnx... It means that I must free those names right?

Comment: Yes. If you don't free it, then it will cause a small memory leak. It won't really affect your application since it's so small anyways, but it's good practice to get into the habit of always freeing memory allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

You create space for each `instrument`, but use the same space (the global variable `name`) for each of their names.